# Is there a word to describe a number that divides evenly by 100?

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

I'm looking for a word that can be used to describe any number that can be divided by 100, without a remainder, e.g. 100, 200, 300, 400, etc. - does it exist?
I was thinking of *centurion*, but that really refers to a person rather than a number.

Comment: Multiple of hundred.

Comment: See also [math.se] Good Luck.

Comment: thanks, but I was looking for a single word, I had thought it would have cent- as its root, as in century, centurion, etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a math site.

Comment: I think you'll have difficulty finding words for multiples larger than two.

Comment: Is there a single word to describe a number that divides evenly by *any* specific number?

Comment: @JasonBassford - *Even*.

Comment: Maybe *100-divisible*.

Comment: @aparente001 *Even* does not describe a number that's divisible by something *specific*. Depending on the number, and the divisor, the result may not be a whole number at all.

Comment: @JasonBassford - [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/even) (of numbers) able to be exactly divided by two.

Comment: @JasonBassford - I was using *even* to mean *divisible by two without a remainder*.

Comment: @aparente001 Oh, yes. The word does mean that, of course. I hadn't been thinking of it that way—or of 2 being the specific target. But it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Century.  Etymologically indebted to Latin cent.  E.g. a centurion had one hundred legionaries.

Comment: In bicycle races, *century* means specifically 100.  For 200, it's a "double century."  Can you show us how you would use the word to express some *multiple* of 100?

Comment: Hi @aparente001. 
In Cricket, it would appear, per this link :-
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_(cricket)
there are "... double (200–299 runs), triple (300–399 runs), and quadruple centuries (400–499 runs), and so on." 
But this convention probably becomes untenable once we get to higher multiples of 100.  So in such cases, I cite the common usage in such historical references as, "... the 8th century BCE ..." per :- 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_alphabet

Comment: @aparente001 for example, in a company, the 100th, 200th, 300th, etc, employee at the company are all centurions, or whatever the correct word is?

Comment: @JosephMcCarthy - Hmm.  I guess we don't have exactly that word.  Maybe *Peter marked our first hundred employees, Chris our second hundred, etc.*